# What applications does abstract algebra and algebraic geometry have in computer science and programming?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, soft-question

I love math and programming. Abstract Algebra and algebraic geometry seems very pleasant to me.

But I also would like to improve my skills as a programmer, but I would love to do so in the fiels that very related to 'real' math (combine my two passions).

We also have a very strong algebraic school where I live, so it would be great to learn from those professors. But, as I've mentioned already, I would love to apply this to elaborate programming.

So what fiels can I chose?

Comment: Algebraic geometry can be applied to the design of digital filters, which are in turn useful in all sorts of applications. See e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209248

Comment: Also, although I am no expert, I believe that algebraic geometry shows up in random number generation. This article looks interesting, but my network connection is misbehaving at the moment so I can't load it to confirm: http://www.naturalspublishing.com/files/published/7d552f4ab41r3a.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) programming language (one of the most widely-used functional languages today) almost entirely builds up on category theoretic stuff.

Algebraic topology is used in high-dimensional data analysis (for example, [persistent homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_homology)).

3D rendering is full of geometry and linear algebra. Probably abstract algebra or algebraic geometry can be usefull there, too.

Answer (score 4):

Cryptography is an area with lots of abstract algebra.

A little bit shows up in functional programming. (Get an impression [here](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1117))

You might want to have a look at the [GAP computer algebra project](http://www.gap-system.org).

Answer (score 3):

The theory of Error-Correcting Codes addresses the problem of recovering the *intended* information when a digital message gets corrupted in transit. A good code is a collection of words made from some alphabet such that if the recipient of a string (of alphabet letters) discovers that the string is not a word (in which case it is a corruption of a word), they can identify the word it was intended to be with little or no ambiguity.

A [Goppa Code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goppa_code) is such a code which is constructed using algebraic geometry. Roughly, one fixes a curve over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ together with a divisor on the curve and a set of $n$ rational points. The code is then the image (in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$) of the associated evaluation map on the Riemann-Roch space of the divisor.